# Altair y axis automatic update when using a selection_interval

Tags: altair, vega-lite

I would like to have the Y Axis adjust to the data displayed when the selection interval is altered. I have seen other examples use `zero=False` in the scale to achieve the Y axis change but I am unable to get it to work with a `selection_interval()`

Here is my code

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

weather = data.seattle_weather()
interval = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'])

base = alt.Chart(weather).mark_rule(size=2).encode(
    x='date:T',
    y=alt.Y('temp_min:Q', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    y2='temp_max:Q',
    color='weather:N'
)

chart = base.encode(
    x=alt.X('date:T', scale=alt.Scale(domain=interval.ref()))
).properties(
    width=800,
    height=300
)

view = base.add_selection(
    interval
).properties(
    width=800,
    height=50,
)

chart & view
```